# Node Wrangler Preview not working

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes

I have the node wrangler add-on turned on, the mapping shortcut works but when I try to do the Ctrl + Shift + LMB shortcut for the preview node it doesn't work. The node just connects to Material Output. I reinstalled Blender and it still won't work. Please help. [image]

Comment: My Node Wrangler (3.4.3 on blender 3.4.1) behaves the same. But the current behaviour gives the same results as before really - it just ommits the Emission shader node that was there previously (the "Viewer" node).

Comment: Also, Viewer node's documentation (https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Nodes/Viewer_Node) currently does not list Shader Editor as a place where it should be available. There's Compositor and Geometry Nodes (where it still works with Shift+Ctrl+LMB). So looks like it was removed.

Comment: Yup, plugging a color socket directly in the surface output or through an emission shader set to a strength of 1 (which is what the viewer node was) provides the same illumination. You do need to be in material preview or rendered view mode though. Here you're in solid view